# Gruntjs less.js file will not build two CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, less

In my `less.js` file I am specifying two CSS files be build for the same app, for some reason it is only building the last file and skipping the first one, how can I build both CSS files, when I run  `grunt build:all`, am I doing something wrong with nesting both files?

```
app: {

  src: [
        '<%= config.node_modules %>/ons-common/dist/styles/day-ons-common.css',
        '<%= config.src %>/app/styles/**/*.less'
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>/app/styles/day-app.css',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapURL: 'day-app.css.map'
        },

  src: [
        '<%= config.node_modules %>/ons-common/dist/styles/night-ons-common.css',
        '<%= config.src %>/app/styles/**/*.less'
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>/app/styles/night-app.css',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapURL: 'night-app.css.map'
        },
},


},
```

Gruntfile.js

```
less: require('./grunt/less'),

lesslint: {
  all: {
    src: [
      '<%= config.src %>/**/*.less',
      '<%= config.src %>/**/*.css'

    ],
    options: {
      csslint: {
        csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
      }
    }
  }

//packaging steps
src: {
    options: {
      archive: 'build/src_<%= pkg.version %>.zip'
    },
    files: [{
        src: ['src/web/**'],
        dest: 'src/'
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should not have two configurations with the same name (`src`). Try it again but this time with the second one named differently like so:

```
app: {

  src: [
        '<%= config.node_modules %>/ons-common/dist/styles/day-ons-common.css',
        '<%= config.src %>/app/styles/**/*.less'
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>/app/styles/day-app.css',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapURL: 'day-app.css.map'
        },

  srcTwo: [
        '<%= config.node_modules %>/ons-common/dist/styles/night-ons-common.css',
        '<%= config.src %>/app/styles/**/*.less'
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>/app/styles/night-app.css',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapURL: 'night-app.css.map'
        },
},


},
```

If this isn't the problem, we are going to need a lot more information on your `gruntfile.js` than just a snippet of your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its funny I tried two different sources and "srcTwo:" still produce the the css file and not the "src"

Comment: I just edited the question to include my gruntfile thanks for any help